# Hive: acquire explicit exclusive lock

Tags: hive, locking, hortonworks-data-platform

Configuration (hortonworks)

- hive: BUILD hive-1.2.1.2.3.0.0
- Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557

I'm trying to execute

```
lock table event_metadata EXCLUSIVE;
```

Hive response:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Current transaction manager does not support explicit lock requests. Transaction manager: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager

In the code there is obvious place where explicit locks are disabled:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/1.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/lockmgr/DbTxnManager.java#DbTxnManager

```
321  @Override
322  public boolean supportsExplicitLock() {
323    return false;
324  }
```

Questions:

how can I make explicit locks work? In what version of hive do they appear?

Here is an example http://www.ericlin.me/how-table-locking-works-in-hive  for cloudera that explicit locks work.

Answer (score 1):

You may set the concurrency parameter on the fly:

```
 set hive.support.concurrency=true;
```

After this you may try executing your command

Comment: Please set the following parameter as well "set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager;"

Answer (score 0):

**`Hive`** includes a **`locking`** feature that uses **`Apache Zookeeper`** for **`locking`**. **`Zookeeper`** implements highly reliable distributed coordination. Other than some additional setup and configuration steps, **`Zookeeper`** is **invisible** to **`Hive`** users.

In the **`$HIVE_HOME/hive-site.xml`** file, set the following properties:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>zk1.site.pvt,zk1.site.pvt,zk1.site.pvt</value> 
    <description>The list of zookeeper servers to talk to. 
                 This is only needed for read/write locks.
   </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether Hive supports concurrency or not.
    A Zookeeper instance must be up and running for the default Hive lock manager to support read-write locks.</description>
</property>
```

After restarting **`hive`**, run the command

```
hive> lock table event_metadata EXCLUSIVE;
```

**Reference:** Programing Hive, O'REILLY

**EDIT:**

[DummyTxnManager.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/86f7af66f03a5b467709a9845d07430b2d729d28/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/lockmgr/DummyTxnManager.java), which provides default Hive behavior, has

```
@Override
  public boolean supportsExplicitLock() {
    return true;
  }
```

**`DummyTxnManager`** replicates **`pre Hive-0.13 behavior`** doesn't support **`transactions`**

**where as**

[DbTxnManager.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/86f7af66f03a5b467709a9845d07430b2d729d28/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/lockmgr/DbTxnManager.java),which stores the **`transactions`** in the **`metastore`** **`database`**, has:

```
@Override
  public boolean supportsExplicitLock() {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately, I already have all that configs in hive-site.xml

Comment: DummyTxnManager, which provides default behavior, has `@Override public boolean supportsExplicitLock() {
     return true;
}`  https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/86f7af66f03a5b467709a9845d07430b2d729d28/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/lockmgr/DummyTxnManager.java

Comment: BTW, I have tested the same on my cloudera VM. exclusive lock works fine. `Hive version - Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.2`

Comment: Vinkal, as I understand, the DummyTxManager has no work with transactions. That can cause some other problems. Am I right? Do you check with Dummy?

Comment: `DummyTxnManager` doesn't support transactions. it replicates `pre Hive-0.13 behavior`. Are we sure zookeeper works fine on your setup? lock works fine on my cloudera machine where zookeeper is up and running. Kindly note that I have not tested DummyTxnManager.

Comment: we use zookeeper for other things. It is ok. And I think, if it doesn't work, the exception should be different.

Comment: did you try to make explicit lock with Dummy or with Db TxnManager?

Comment: I tried to make explicit lock with DbTxnManager on Cloudera machine. I mentioned DummyTxnManager to show the difference in supportsExplicitLock() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93533/discussion-between-natalia-and-vinkal).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager;

unlock table *tablename*;